# Why JComboBox needs item -1 while building?

Tags: java, swing, custom-controls, jcombobox

I'm trying to understand why the following code doesn't work:

```
           JComboBox status = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
           status.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel() {
            @Override
            public void addElement(Object anObject) {
                statusList.add((RequirementStatus) anObject);
                super.addElement(anObject);
            }

            @Override
            public int getSize() {
                return statusList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getElementAt(int index) {
                return index >= 0 && index < statusList.size()
                        ? statusList.get(index) : null;
            }
        });
        status.setRenderer(new ListCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
                    Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
                    boolean cellHasFocus) {

                return index >= 0 ? new JLabel(
                        ((RequirementStatus) ((ComboBoxModel) status.getModel())
                        .getElementAt(index)).getStatus())
                        : new JLabel("");
            }
        });
```

And this one does:

```
           JComboBox status = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
           status.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel() {
            @Override
            public void addElement(Object anObject) {
                statusList.add((RequirementStatus) anObject);
                super.addElement(anObject);
            }

            @Override
            public int getSize() {
                return statusList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getElementAt(int index) {
                return statusList.get(index);
            }
        });
        status.setRenderer(new ListCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
                    Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
                    boolean cellHasFocus) {

                return index >= 0 ? new JLabel(
                        ((RequirementStatus) ((ComboBoxModel) status.getModel())
                        .getElementAt(index)).getStatus())
                        : new JLabel("-none-");
            }
        });
```

I had to add that condition to the code because for some reason while building the GUI the code requests to render the element at position -1. If I don't return a label with some text, the Combo Box doesn't show at all.

**Edit:**

This is the error I get if this workaround is not present:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:324)
    at net.sourceforge.javydreamercsw.client.ui.nodes.actions.EditRequirementDialog$5.getElementAt(EditRequirementDialog.java:119)
    at net.sourceforge.javydreamercsw.client.ui.nodes.actions.EditRequirementDialog$6.getListCellRendererComponent(EditRequirementDialog.java:127)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.getDisplaySize(BasicComboBoxUI.java:1334)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.getMinimumSize(BasicComboBoxUI.java:903)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.getPreferredSize(BasicComboBoxUI.java:892)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1642)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$ComponentSpring.calculateNonlinkedPreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:2944)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$ComponentSpring.calculatePreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:2905)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Spring.getPreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1325)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.getSpringSize(GroupLayout.java:1604)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculateSize(GroupLayout.java:1593)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculatePreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1568)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Spring.getPreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1325)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.getSpringSize(GroupLayout.java:1604)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculateSize(GroupLayout.java:1593)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculatePreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1568)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Spring.getPreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1325)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.getSpringSize(GroupLayout.java:1604)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculateSize(GroupLayout.java:1593)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculatePreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1568)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Spring.getPreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1325)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.getSpringSize(GroupLayout.java:1604)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculateSize(GroupLayout.java:1590)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculatePreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1568)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Spring.getPreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1325)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.getSpringSize(GroupLayout.java:1604)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculateSize(GroupLayout.java:1588)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculatePreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1568)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Spring.getPreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1325)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.getSpringSize(GroupLayout.java:1604)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculateSize(GroupLayout.java:1588)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculatePreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1568)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Spring.getPreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1325)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$SequentialGroup.setValidSize(GroupLayout.java:1972)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.setSize(GroupLayout.java:1553)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.calculateAutopadding(GroupLayout.java:1058)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.layoutContainer(GroupLayout.java:897)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1419)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1408)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1505)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1511)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1511)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1511)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1478)
    at java.awt.Dialog.conditionalShow(Dialog.java:890)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1036)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1591)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1543)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:843)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:987)
    at net.sourceforge.javydreamercsw.client.ui.nodes.actions.EditRequirementAction$1.run(EditRequirementAction.java:33)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:627)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:625)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:636)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

I know it should be an easy thing, like a flag to set but I can't find it.

Any ideas?

**Solution:**
Remove the Model override and change renderer code as follows:

```
status.setRenderer(new ListCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
                    Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
                    boolean cellHasFocus) {
                return index >= 0 ? new JLabel(
                        ((RequirementStatus) value).getStatus())
                        : new JLabel(((RequirementStatus) list.getSelectedValue()).getStatus());
            }
        });
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You are aware that `((ComboBoxModel) status.getModel())
                        .getElementAt(index))` is strictly equivalent to the parameter `value` provided? Anyway, if when displayed for the first time, the current selected object is `null` and `null` is not part of your model, the UI has no other choice than providing -1 as the index

Comment: Why are you overriding the model? I don't see any reason to do this. If you are storing a custom object in the model all you need to do is provide a custom renderer to display the data from the object.

Comment: @Guillaume Polet: Thanks for the value pointer. Fixed that.

Comment: @camickr: Fixed that as well. It was due to NetBeans default code generation which sets the model to a string one. I removed that and works now without overriding the model.

Comment: I tried setSelectedIndex without luck. Still requesting the -1 index. From the stack trace seems to be during the process of drawing the component: at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.getDisplaySize(BasicComboBoxUI.java:1334)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.getMinimumSize(BasicComboBoxUI.java:903)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.getPreferredSize(BasicComboBoxUI.java:892)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1642)

Comment: The other side effect is that I can't select items from the list. I made sure the lists are enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JComboBox#setRenderer javadoc:

> To display the selected item, aRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent is called, passing the list object and an index of -1.

Comment: This seems to explain the main question.

Comment: Removing the model override and changing the renderer did the trick. See question for edited code.

Comment: Note that the value is already the selected value, so no need to get it again from the list. Your renderer also doesn't paint selected/focus status. Better to extend the DefaultListCellRenderer and pass value.getStatus() to super.getListCellRendererComponent()